# Lost file when renaming it

Tags: mv

I wrote a shell script to rename a whole bunch of files. Unfortunately, I accidentally saved it with Windows EOL so it messed up the file names with control-m characters at the end of each file.

I was in the process of renaming them individually when I made yet another mistake:

```
mv abc\ -\ 123.dat^M abc\ -\ 123.da
```

Once noticing I missed a 't' at the end of the name, and without checking if the file is still there (I had no reason to suspect otherwise), I did a quick:

```
mv *.da *.dat
```

My file was gone... There were no errors either.

Anyone know what could have happened to it?

I'm running CentOS 6, OS FS is ext4, FS of raid array where this happened is XFS.

Thanks,
E.

Comment: So the both commands ran without errors?

Comment: Before running the second command, how many files matched `*.dat`? The shell will expand `mv *.da *.dat` into `mv` plus the name of each `*.da` file, plus the name of each `*.dat` file. The results of the command won’t do what you were trying to do. Exactly what happened depends on what files you had that match `*.dat`. What do you get for `ls *.dat` now?

Comment: @jw013 It will expand `*.da *.dat` all into one long string. If it ran without errors, either the last file was a directory, or E71 had only one `*.da` file and no more than one `*.dat` file.

Comment: @amarillo You're right. Since the command ran without error, OP probably just clobbered whatever existing .dat file he had.

Comment: One more thing @E71: what is the output of `type mv`? Sometimes `mv` is aliased to `mv -i`, which would prevent you from clobbering any existing `*.dat` file like jw013 was saying. Another possibility is that you didn’t overwrite any files, and you renamed `123.da` to `*.dat` with a literal asterisk in the filename.

Comment: @amarillo: Thanks for that, I see what I did wrong and quite frankly I'm scared to death of using `mv` now. It overwrote the other file. I'm so used to using `ren *.ext1 *.ext2` to change extensions on Windows that I made the grave assumption that the same kind of syntax would work for `mv`. Didn't even warn me -- not sure why since `mv` is not aliased to `mv -f` or anything.

Comment: `mv -f` is bad news when you don’t want it. You may want to do `alias mv='mv -i'` though. I wasn't aware that Windows could use that sort of syntax. I hope the file you overwrote wasn't irreplaceable. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in comments, but answering a comment needs formatting: `mv` by default WILL replace an existing file (which `-i` prevents) BUT NOT if unwritable (which `-f` overrides):

```
           target does  target exists  target exists 
command    not exist    and writable   NOT writable

mv -i      create       prompt         prompt
mv         create       REPLACE        prompt
mv -f      create       REPLACE        REPLACE
```

Comment: Huh, you’re right. The man page for `mv` wasn’t terribly clear on that. Thanks.